# Is there something similar to JOptionPane in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface, joptionpane

I'm trying to create a simple game in **Objective-C.** In **Java** I could use `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` to create a simple window with a message or `JOPtionPane.showInputDialog` to create a simple input window... Is there's something similar in Objective-C? (Or Cocoa, or whatever I could use...)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `JOptionPane`, but you can use `UIAlertView` to do both of those things.  By default, it displays a message with either one or two buttons.  As of iOS 5, it also has style properties to give it a `UITextField`, which would make a simple input prompt.

Comment: ¿And how about doing that in Mac? I need a windows that pops out and aks for user input and another windows that shows a message...

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you were using iOS.  On OS X, you can use NSAlert to accomplish the same thing.  Use the accessoryView to add an Input box.

Comment: Ok, i can use NSAlert to display information, but how can I request user input? Do I have to use something more complicated such as NSPanel?